# Passing an array of arrays to a input tensor

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite, tensorflow-c++

I'm working into breaking an image(540x360) to 60x60 matrix referred by `cv::Mat imga` in my code, then normalizing in `cv::Mat imga_normalized` and finally passing each 60x60 normalized to a  `std::vector<cv::Mat> arrayimganorm`, which has 54 elements (540 / 60 = 9; 360 / 60 = 6; 9x6 = 54).

```cpp
for (int r = 0; r < src.rows; r += 60) //src.rows = 540
{
    for (int c = 0; c < src.cols; c += 60) //src.cols = 360
    {

        cv::Mat imga = src(cv::Range(r, (r + 60)), cv::Range(c, (c + 60))).clone();

        imga.convertTo(imga_normalize, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255, 0); 

        arrayimganorm.push_back(imga_normalize);

    }
}
```

After this I need to copy the data from arrayimganorm to a input tensor, but I don't know how.

I already tried this 2 ways, but they don't work as well:

1. Without `memcpy`:

```cpp
std::vector<cv::Mat>* data = &arrayimganorm;

for(int w = 0; w < 54; w++)
{
    interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0)[w] = *(data++);
}
// This gaves me there is no proper conversion function for
// std::vector<cv::Mat> to float. What I misunderstood is that
// imga_normalize it's an CV_32 and the first inputs dimension is 54.
```

2. With `memcpy`:

```cpp
for(int w = 0; w < 54; w++)
{
    memcpy(interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0)[w], arrayimganorm[w].data , arrayimganorm[w].total() * arrayimganorm[w].elemSize());
}
// This gives me type argument is incompatible with type parameter
```

```cpp
model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromBuffer(ptr, sizeof(ptr));
if (model == nullptr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load model\n");
    exit(-1);
}

tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model.get(), resolver)(&interpreter);

if (interpreter == nullptr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initiate the interpreter\n");
    exit(-1);
}

interpreter->ResizeInputTensor(0, { 54, 60, 60, 1 });
// I did this because my standard input tensor has 1 x 60 x 60 x 1
// dimensions (converted .pb to tflite, which is another misunderstood
// question, maybe for other day.. but just sayin in .pb I got
// {? x 60 x 60 x 1} dimensions and the conversion got me
// 1 x 60 x 60 x 1), but I need to get faster results and invoking
// interpreter to one by one input were consuming a lot of time, so I
// changed to 54, because it's 54 60x60 matrix.
... 
auto valor = interpreter->tensor(0)->dims->data[0]; //prints 54
auto height = interpreter->tensor(0)->dims->data[1]; //prints 60
auto width = interpreter->tensor(0)->dims->data[2]; //prints 60
auto channels = interpreter->tensor(0)->dims->data[3]; //prints 1
```

Any idea of how can I pass this array of array to the input tensor?

Comment: Why arrayimganorm + 1 isn't = arrayimgnorm[1]? Because the type of data is std::vector<cv::Mat> right? So in my mind, that would gets the sizeof this type of data, then points to the another arrayimgnorm

Comment: Oops, I meant `data`, not `arrayimganorm`.

Comment: `std::vector<cv::Mat>* data = &arrayimganorm;` doesn't point at the data of the vector, just at its "handle" (e.g. pointer and size in a struct). It should be `cv::Mat* data = &arrayimgnorm[0]` or `cv::Mat* data = arrayimgnorm.data()`.

Comment: Fixed, thanks! But now I got: there is no proper conversion function for <cv::Mat> to float, I think maybe this data attribution only can be done with memcpy for ungiving me this different data types error.

Comment: I have no experience with either Tensorflow or OpenCV, but if there isn't some special interoperability between them, you might have to transfer every single `float` explicitly.